# How to normalize stock exchange indexes

Tags: statistics, econometrics, index, normalization

I am doing an academic research in behavioral finance and I need to calculate my abnormal return based on the normalized returns of the stock exchange index being the S&P 500. In other words, I have the daily return for the S&P 500, I need to find the normalized daily return of the S&P 500.

Comment: do you have a definition of 'normalized return'?  it's not a standard measurement

Comment: I suppose you can call them "standardized returns"

Comment: traditionally you normalize a dataset by taking individual values, subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard deviation.  the result are in effect Z-scores.  this isn't really something that's done often though, and given what you describe you're trying to do, it sounds like a bit of an unusual application.

Comment: Well, you can do it when your dataset is not normalized? My dataset is a time-series so that procedure does not apply for it. do you have any other suggestion?